# Amigobot AMCL does not work when namespace is used, no laser scan is recieved

Tags: ros-noetic, laserscan, rosaria

I am using the amigobot and the rosaria library to communicate with the robot. Typically, I lauch the rosaria, publush_tf, and rplidar node and on my computer the amcl_diff_corrected and the plan_in_odom and the navigation stack works.

Because of the project I have made a launch file (amigobot_0.launch) launching the rosaria, publush_tf, and rplidar node, in which I am using namespace because I eventually will use 4 of them. On my computer I launch the amcl(amcl_diff_corrected_0), and the move base nodes(plan_in_odom_0) that I modified from the amigobot_2dnav pgk, that my school provided.
When I launch the amcl_diff_corrected_0 I have a warning saying: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1700825259.828684 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /tb3_0/scan topic.
Here are the files I am talking about: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/13YW_tbiLgepvUVu0ixbcS0qNWrIVOgpS?usp=sharing

I cannot understand why this is happening.
Thank you in advance

[image: cdm]

[image: rqt_graph]